# Missing operations in gooddata java SDK?

Tags: gooddata

I'm trying to confirm all the calls we currently make are supported in Gooddata's java sdk (https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-java/) before we decide whether to update to use this.

I have confirmed all cases except 2 and am hoping that someone might be able to suggest how I might make these calls in the java SDK today.

list all users in a domain: (https://help.gooddata.com/display/API/API+Reference#/reference/users/manage-users-in-a-domain/list-all-users-in-a-domain)

assign a userfilter to a user (https://help.gooddata.com/display/API/API+Reference#/reference/data-and-object-permissions/assign-a-data-permission-to-a-user/assign-a-data-permission-to-a-user)

I just want to confirm these operations are not currently supported before I investigate effort to add them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are right and there is no built in support for GoodData domain (also called organisation) user handling (yet). On the other hand using "com.gooddata.sdk.service.httpcomponents" you can easily work with any GoodData API within your code.

In case you wouldn't be tied to strictly to Java - there is possibility to use bit more robust "Ruby SDK" - https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ruby-doc/docs/getting_started.html which natively contains user management

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to shoot feature request directly into the repository (https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-java/issues) - we will check that up and most likely add the support soon (or at least give you the estimate).